# Calling a interface method using static variable in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have an application where an interface is used.

```
public interface INotificationError
{
    void Notification(Erros.ETypes error, Exception e);
}
```

In some other class say `ClassName`, they have assigned a static variable like the following:

```
public static INotificationError ErrorDispatch;
```

They used to call the defined method using the following line.

```
ClassName.ErrorDispatch.Notification(ERROR, ex);
```

How come it is possible to call this method? Please explain?

Comment: `ClassName.ErrorDispatch.Notification(ERROR, ex);`

Comment: _"How come it is possible to call this method? Please explain?"_ - please explain what answers you're looking for. Why would it be _impossible_ to call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassName.ErrorDispatch` refers to static member `ErroDispatch` inside class `ClassName`, where `ErroDispatch` is initiliazed like this:

```
ErroDispatch  = new DerivedFromINotificationErrorClass();
```

So you can call members of that class. The *access* to that member is static, but that member is usual instance of some class that implements `INotificationError` interface (in my example this is `DerivedFromINotificationErrorClass`)

Comment: Yes you are right..I could find the initialization part in Main class like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassName` was probably a property with the name matching your class name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the references on ClassName ErrorDispatch, somewhere there will be assignment to the implementing class, which implements the INotificationError interface, otherwise it would cause null reference exception.